# Drag & drop into web browser just re-downloads the file when using intranet zone site with no domain

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

My problem is simple. I am using the standard methodology in HTML in JavaScript to get files dropped from the desktop:

1. Listen to `dragover` event and accept them all
2. Listen to `drop` event and do something with `event.dataTransfer.files`

You can see a very common example of what I'm doing here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9C2EF/449/

```
<script language="javascript">
    function dodrop(event)
{
  var dt = event.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  var count = files.length;
  output("File Count: " + count + "\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      output(" File " + i + ":\n(" + (typeof files[i]) + ") : <" + files[i] + " > " +
             files[i].name + " " + files[i].size + "\n");
    }
}

function output(text)
{
  document.getElementById("output").textContent += text;
  //dump(text);
}
</script>

<div id="output" style="min-height: 200px; white-space: pre; border: 1px solid black;"
     ondragenter="document.getElementById('output').textContent = ''; event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();"
     ondragover="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();"
     ondrop="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
     dodrop(event);">
     DROP FILES HERE FROM FINDER OR EXPLORER
</div>
```

Which is just a modified-to-work version of what Mozilla has here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#files.28.29

This code works without issue in all scenarios EXCEPT when I use a local intranet page without the domain on WINDOWS 8 machines. For example, `http://local-server/test/` will not work. All it will do is, when the file is dragged in, re-download the file (and JS never gets the `dragOver` event). However, using `http://local-server.mycompanydomain.com/test/` WILL work as expected.

This does not occur on other OSes. The issue was seen with all browsers on WIN 8.

Has anyone encountered this?